# Xcode UIView for every link that is clicked

Tags: xcode, uiview, uitabbar

Hi
I want to create an app that displays a web site and to be able to open the link in a new session of the UIView every time a user clicks on a link.
I need it to act like that because i want to create an effect whenever the UIView loads and i don't want to create tons of UIView for all of the pages.
Actually, i already displayed a website with the uiview but i cant control how the uiview appears after a link is selected and i cant change the site code.
Does anyone know how to do it inside a tab bar app on xcode?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know if you use [UIWebViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and the methods appropriately to stop the link loading and open the link in a new View.

Answer (score 1):

i used a webview for each tab and it worked.
I've used this method
because it was more accessible and it loaded
all of the webviews
together instead of loading one.
Thanks